# My nav bar is smaller than the child elements

Tags: html, css, nav

My problem so far is that the ".nav" div doesn't contain the li elements inside it. I have tried adding "clearfix" to the div, and I've tried "overflow:hidden" but nothing seems to work. 
Technically I can change the .nav height to 200px or something along those lines, but I was hoping there was a way to make it happen automatically since the height is set to "auto"

Apologies if this has been answered hundreds of times before, but I'm lost

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
}


/* full-width header */

.jumbotron {
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: silver;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 font-family: 'Rockwell' , serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-right: 2%;  
}

/*Nav*/

.nav {
 background-color: #170130;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.nav ul {
 width: 80%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: justify;
    min-width: 00px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul:after {
 content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;

}

.bytown-logo {
 max-height: 150px;
 margin-top:1em;
}
/* grid */

.box, 
.sidebar {
 height: 200px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
 background-color: silver;
 height: 200px;
}

.box h2,
.sidebar h2 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.sidebar, 
.sidebar h2, 
.sidebar p  {
 background-color: #682749;
}

/* footer */

footer {
 position: relative;
 bottom:0px;
 background-color: #170130;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
} 
/*social media links*/
.social-links {
 display: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #170130;
}

.social-links li {
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 20px;
} 

.logo {
 max-height: 28px;
}


/* The following is all the SKELETON grid system */
/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
  font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222; }


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }


/* Links
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
a {
  color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE; }


/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }


/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Bytown Events - Ottawa's Premiere" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

 <title>Bytown Events | Event Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>bytown events</h1>
 </div>
    <div  class="nav clearfix">
       
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img class="bytown-logo" src="images/bytown-logo-transparent.png" alt="Bytown Events logo"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
     </div>
     
        
</header>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="box three columns" id="talent-booking">
    <h2>Talent Booking</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="security">
   <h2>Security</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="food">
   <h2>Food & Catering</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar three columns" id="about us">
   <h2>About us</h2>
   <p>Loremipsumdolor
    sitamet,consectetur 
    adipisicingelit,sed
    doeiusmodtempor
    incididuntutlabore
         <br><br>
         “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
    “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
          <br><br>
         “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
    “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
   </p> 
  </div>
   </div><!-- END ROW -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="box three columns" id="promotions">
    <h2>Promotions & Marketing</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="setup">
   <h2>Set Up</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="equipment">
   <h2>Equipment & Audio</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->

  <footer>
   <ul class="social-links">
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/pinterest.png"></a></li>
   </ul>
   
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use float:left;

```
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

---

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; 
    
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

body {
 margin: 0px;
}


/* full-width header */

.jumbotron {
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: silver;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 font-family: 'Rockwell' , serif;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-right: 2%;  
}

/*Nav*/

.nav {
 background-color: #170130;
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.nav ul {
 width: 80%;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: justify;
    min-width: 00px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav ul:after {
 content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
}

.nav ul li {
 float: left;
}

.nav ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 26px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 200;

}

.bytown-logo {
 max-height: 150px;
 margin-top:1em;
}
/* grid */

.box, 
.sidebar {
 height: 200px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.box {
 background-color: silver;
 height: 200px;
}

.box h2,
.sidebar h2 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.container {
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.sidebar, 
.sidebar h2, 
.sidebar p  {
 background-color: #682749;
}

/* footer */

footer {
 position: relative;
 bottom:0px;
 background-color: #170130;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60px;
} 
/*social media links*/
.social-links {
 display: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #170130;
}

.social-links li {
 position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 display: inline;
 padding-left: 20px;
} 

.logo {
 max-height: 28px;
}


/* The following is all the SKELETON grid system */
/*
* Skeleton V2.0.4
* Copyright 2014, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 12/29/2014
*/


/* Table of contents
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
- Grid
- Base Styles
- Typography
- Links
- Buttons
- Forms
- Lists
- Code
- Tables
- Spacing
- Utilities
- Clearing
- Media Queries
*/


/* Grid
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.column,
.columns {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 400px */
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .container {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 0; }
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  .container {
    width: 80%; }
  .column,
  .columns {
    margin-left: 4%; }
  .column:first-child,
  .columns:first-child {
    margin-left: 0; }

  .one.column,
  .one.columns                    { width: 4.66666666667%; }
  .two.columns                    { width: 13.3333333333%; }
  .three.columns                  { width: 22%;            }
  .four.columns                   { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .five.columns                   { width: 39.3333333333%; }
  .six.columns                    { width: 48%;            }
  .seven.columns                  { width: 56.6666666667%; }
  .eight.columns                  { width: 65.3333333333%; }
  .nine.columns                   { width: 74.0%;          }
  .ten.columns                    { width: 82.6666666667%; }
  .eleven.columns                 { width: 91.3333333333%; }
  .twelve.columns                 { width: 100%; margin-left: 0; }

  .one-third.column               { width: 30.6666666667%; }
  .two-thirds.column              { width: 65.3333333333%; }

  .one-half.column                { width: 48%; }

  /* Offsets */
  .offset-by-one.column,
  .offset-by-one.columns          { margin-left: 8.66666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two.column,
  .offset-by-two.columns          { margin-left: 17.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-three.column,
  .offset-by-three.columns        { margin-left: 26%;            }
  .offset-by-four.column,
  .offset-by-four.columns         { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-five.column,
  .offset-by-five.columns         { margin-left: 43.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-six.column,
  .offset-by-six.columns          { margin-left: 52%;            }
  .offset-by-seven.column,
  .offset-by-seven.columns        { margin-left: 60.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eight.column,
  .offset-by-eight.columns        { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }
  .offset-by-nine.column,
  .offset-by-nine.columns         { margin-left: 78.0%;          }
  .offset-by-ten.column,
  .offset-by-ten.columns          { margin-left: 86.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-eleven.column,
  .offset-by-eleven.columns       { margin-left: 95.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-third.column,
  .offset-by-one-third.columns    { margin-left: 34.6666666667%; }
  .offset-by-two-thirds.column,
  .offset-by-two-thirds.columns   { margin-left: 69.3333333333%; }

  .offset-by-one-half.column,
  .offset-by-one-half.columns     { margin-left: 52%; }

}


/* Base Styles
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* NOTE
html is set to 62.5% so that all the REM measurements throughout Skeleton
are based on 10px sizing. So basically 1.5rem = 15px :) */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
body {
  font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222; }


/* Typography
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300; }
h1 { font-size: 4.0rem; line-height: 1.2;  letter-spacing: -.1rem;}
h2 { font-size: 3.6rem; line-height: 1.25; letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3.0rem; line-height: 1.3;  letter-spacing: -.1rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.4rem; line-height: 1.35; letter-spacing: -.08rem; }
h5 { font-size: 1.8rem; line-height: 1.5;  letter-spacing: -.05rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 1.6;  letter-spacing: 0; }

/* Larger than phablet */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
  h1 { font-size: 5.0rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 4.2rem; }
  h3 { font-size: 3.6rem; }
  h4 { font-size: 3.0rem; }
  h5 { font-size: 2.4rem; }
  h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
}

p {
  margin-top: 0; }


/* Links
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
a {
  color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE; }


/* Buttons
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 38px;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.button:hover,
button:hover,
input[type="submit"]:hover,
input[type="reset"]:hover,
input[type="button"]:hover,
.button:focus,
button:focus,
input[type="submit"]:focus,
input[type="reset"]:focus,
input[type="button"]:focus {
  color: #333;
  border-color: #888;
  outline: 0; }
.button.button-primary,
button.button-primary,
input[type="submit"].button-primary,
input[type="reset"].button-primary,
input[type="button"].button-primary {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #33C3F0;
  border-color: #33C3F0; }
.button.button-primary:hover,
button.button-primary:hover,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:hover,
input[type="button"].button-primary:hover,
.button.button-primary:focus,
button.button-primary:focus,
input[type="submit"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="reset"].button-primary:focus,
input[type="button"].button-primary:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #1EAEDB;
  border-color: #1EAEDB; }


/* Forms
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea,
select {
  height: 38px;
  padding: 6px 10px; /* The 6px vertically centers text on FF, ignored by Webkit */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #D1D1D1;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
/* Removes awkward default styles on some inputs for iOS */
input[type="email"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="text"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
textarea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none; }
textarea {
  min-height: 65px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px; }
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
select:focus {
  border: 1px solid #33C3F0;
  outline: 0; }
label,
legend {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 600; }
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 0; }
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline; }
label > .label-body {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5rem;
  font-weight: normal; }


/* Lists
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
ul {
  list-style: circle inside; }
ol {
  list-style: decimal inside; }
ol, ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0; }
ul ul,
ul ol,
ol ol,
ol ul {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem 3rem;
  font-size: 90%; }
li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }


/* Code
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
code {
  padding: .2rem .5rem;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 90%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
  border-radius: 4px; }
pre > code {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  white-space: pre; }


/* Tables
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
th,
td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }
th:first-child,
td:first-child {
  padding-left: 0; }
th:last-child,
td:last-child {
  padding-right: 0; }


/* Spacing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
button,
.button {
  margin-bottom: 1rem; }
input,
textarea,
select,
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem; }
pre,
blockquote,
dl,
figure,
table,
p,
ul,
ol,
form {
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem; }


/* Utilities
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.u-full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-max-full-width {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box; }
.u-pull-right {
  float: right; }
.u-pull-left {
  float: left; }


/* Misc
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
hr {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.5rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E1E1E1; }


/* Clearing
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after,
.row:after,
.u-cf {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Bytown Events - Ottawa's Premiere" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

 <title>Bytown Events | Event Management</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>bytown events</h1>
 </div>
    <div  class="nav clearfix">
       
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><img class="bytown-logo" src="images/bytown-logo-transparent.png" alt="Bytown Events logo"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li> 
            </ul>
     </div>
     
        
</header>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
  <div class="box three columns" id="talent-booking">
    <h2>Talent Booking</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="security">
   <h2>Security</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="food">
   <h2>Food & Catering</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar three columns" id="about us">
   <h2>About us</h2>
   <p>Loremipsumdolor
    sitamet,consectetur 
    adipisicingelit,sed
    doeiusmodtempor
    incididuntutlabore
         <br><br>
         “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
    “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
          <br><br>
         “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
    “Loremipsumdolorsit
    amet,consectetur”
   </p> 
  </div>
   </div><!-- END ROW -->
   <div class="row">
    <div class="box three columns" id="promotions">
    <h2>Promotions & Marketing</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="setup">
   <h2>Set Up</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box three columns" id="equipment">
   <h2>Equipment & Audio</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
  </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->

  <footer>
   <ul class="social-links">
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="logo" src="images/pinterest.png"></a></li>
   </ul>
   
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I inherited this code from someone and I was wondering if it was the grid system making the problem. Also, Now all the elements are bunched up so I guess I now have a new problem :/ - on to the next!

Comment: Never give up! ;) @JpNuyens